"Connection failed" to Azure ML in Fabric Data Pipeline
When I try to establish a connection with Azure ML from a Fabric Data Pipeline, I get an error saying:

Request sent to Azure ML Service for operation 'validateWorkspace' failed with http status code 'Unauthorized'. Error message from Azure ML Service: '{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience","message":"The access token has been obtained for wrong audience or resource 'https://ml.azure.com'. It should exactly match with one of the allowed audiences 'https://management.core.windows.net/','https://management.core.windows.net','https://management.azure.com/','https://management.azure.com'."}}'.

And if I run the Azure Machine Learning project, I get the error shown in the picture.
With the given settings, all available batch endpoints show up - so it actually should connect correctly.
I followed this tutorial, but can't solve the error described above.
How can I overcome this error?
